# Non-root user cannot change Samba password

Tags: linux, password, samba, passwd, samba4

Samba users cannot change their own passwords. The password can only be changed using root account using the command

```
smbpasswd -a <username>
```

But I want users be able to change their passwords by their own. When password is tried to changed using a non-root account I get the below error message.

```
$ smbpasswd
Old SMB password:
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Could not connect to machine 127.0.0.1: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Failed to change password for user1
```

Any reasons for this? How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to start the smbd daemon on the local machine. Or use option `-r somemachine` to connect to a remote server that holds the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Every authentication method is generally checked against the Domain. As smb.conf is specified as "security=ads", so when a user authentication is checked it's always checked against the Domain first and when the user is reported as "Not Found or logon failure" it will not proceed with next method i.e sam (local user database).

Specify the following line in Global Section of smb.conf

```
 auth methods = guest sam_ignoredomain winbind:ntdomain
```

Then, restart smb service

Comment: I can't find an `auth methods` (or anything that looks similar) in the [man page for smb.conf](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html). Is it still valid, and if so do you have a current documentation reference for it, please?